# How to disable/inactive the data in mongoDB database instead of delete using nodejs

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

when I hit the delete method in postman I need to disable the data in MongoDB instead of completely delete. how to do that?

```
 router.delete("/admin/delete_profile/:id", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    await SomeModel.findByIdAndDelete(req.params.id.trim());
    return send(res, RESPONSE.SUCCESS);
  } catch (err) {
   // res.status(404).send(err.message);
    return send(res, RESPONSE.UNKNOWN_ERROR);
  }
});
```

schema.js

```
const { json } = require("body-parser");
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const SomeModelSchema = new Schema({
  first_name: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },

  last_name: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },

  image: {
    data: Buffer,
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
});

module.exports = mongoose.model("SomeModel", SomeModelSchema);
```

Comment: Can you post the model schema declaration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, the approach suggested by @PawanYadav is a good one in my opinion.
Declare a `Boolean` flag `isActive` in your Schema (default to `true`):

```
const SomeModelSchema = new Schema({
  first_name: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  last_name: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  image: {
    data: Buffer,
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  isActive: {
    type: Boolean,
    default: true,
  }
});
```

And use `findByIdAndUpdate` to set the flag to `false` to disable the data:

```
try {
    await SomeModel.findByIdAndUpdate(req.params.id.trim(), {
      isActive: false,
    });
    return send(res, RESPONSE.SUCCESS);
  } catch (err) {
    // res.status(404).send(err.message);
    return send(res, RESPONSE.UNKNOWN_ERROR);
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can keep a key like `isActive:true` in your database for soft delete purpose.When you hit delete api you can simply change this key to false.In this way you can differentiate this document from others and when you want list you can check for documents with `isActive:true` in your query.